# Is there a way to make a div have the size of the text content?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a chat in html but I'm having trouble with the text bubbles, since the div becomes bigger than the text when it breaks:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bv5r.png)

In the first image, you can see the chat, in the second, the inspect of the element, and in the third, the part (show in red) that I want to remove. Also, I tried to use `width: min-content` in the div , but didn't have the result I wanted (next image):
[image link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dj5C.png)

I included the code in codepen to help:
https://codepen.io/nidilap/pen/YzwzMNP

Does someone have a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide some of your code so that people have a way to tell what's happening.

Comment: Remove ``%5`` in padding code section. Just write this: ``padding: 5px;``

Comment: Still not working properly Goksel :/

Comment: Ok. You can add ``text-align: justify;`` in your ``.textoTF`` and ``.textoTC`` for adjusting spaces between words.

Comment: I also tried this, but it creates white spaces between the words and I want the text aligned to the left. Thanks for the answer though.